# How to handle large images in Android activity

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, memory-management

I am creating a game, and the background image for each activity is around 500kb in size. It consists of a couple of activities so when I press the back button it should go back to the one it came from. There is no saving state involved but it still runs out of memory. What can I do to manage memory better? Each activity has a background image, and also 1-2 smaller images.

I am setting the background images straight from xml.

Here is the onStop method that I generally use for all the activities.

```
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bg);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
    setContentView(new View(this));
}
```

Comment: A first step would be to shrink the images as much as you can without affecting too much the quality. TinyPng is a tool that should provide some great results https://tinypng.com/

Comment: Voting to close as too broad not because what you want is bad, but because with no code and such vague requirements we can only give vague answers.  But I'd look into using an LRUCache to limit the amount of memory used by all images (by forcing them into a closed pool) as a good first step. Also make sure that activities holding very large images release them when they don't need to display them (which plays into the LRU cache).

Comment: Sorry this is the first application I am making, so I don't know much about memory management. How do I release the images? Ill post some code in a few minutes.

Comment: @TirthAllsparkRami The expectation is that you've at least gone through: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html which goes through handling bitmap memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try shrinking your image. There are many online editing tools for that. Shrink the image as much as you can without compromising much with the quality of the picture. Good Luck.